# high voltage multiplexer for battery cell monitoring

Tags: voltage, batteries, multiplexer

I'm working on a battery management solution with 50.4V battery (36 cells in series with 1.4V a single cell voltage) for automotive application.
i'm planning on using multiplexer and differential amplifier to monitor the voltage of these cells with a microcontroller.
The problem here is that a multiplexer maximun voltage input is 36V/40V from what i found.
so is there any automotive multiplexer able to handle this voltage (50.4V)?
If not can i use a voltage divider for the cells with a higher voltage than 36V ? in this case i'm a little bit worried about the accuracy and the precision of the measurement.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using a battery cell monitor IC? They are purpose built for this and feature additional benefits

Comment: yes but the problem is that i'm going for active cell balancing system and i'm planing on driving external mosfets for the balancing with 100Khz frequency which none of the existed battery cell monitor can provide this high frequency so i dropped this idea of using IC and i'm trying to find a discrete solution

Comment: checkout the MAX378 by MaximIntegrated, this is good for 65V

Comment: you could use the cell balancing IC just for battery monitoring, and still have your own separate active cell balancing; if you want to do it discretely, you need voltage dividers, on each cell, and op-amps as voltage buffers, then mux that into the ADC